# Using Fabric on cascated host environment

Tags: fabric

I'm trying to use Fabric to connect to several nodes (Ubuntu VMs), but I can not reach all nodes from VM where Fabric is installed. Instead I need to go first to one specific node called entry point and from this entry point to another VM where from that all VMs are reachable. Please see figure below. Any suggestions on how to use fabric to achieve this?

[Network Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDXZb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

With more than 1 "jump" the easiest way to achieve it is by letting Fabric read your `~/.ssh/config`'s ProxyCommand directives (or equivalent).
Have a look at [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/execution.html#leveraging-native-ssh-config-files).

In your configuration file you should have something like the following:

```
Host entryPoint
  HostName your-entrypoint-hostname-or-ipaddress

Host VM0
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p entryPoint

Host VM1 VM2 VMN
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p VM0
```

For a single jump you may consider using `env.gateway` instead.

A slight variation, using `nc`:

```
Host entryPoint
  HostName your-entrypoint-hostname-or-ipaddress

Host VM0
  ProxyCommand ssh -q entryPoint nc -q0 %h:%p

Host VM1 VM2 VMN
  ProxyCommand ssh -q VM0 nc -q0 %h:%p
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciated. It works well for entryPoint and VM0. However for the third jump like in the example VM1, fabric asks for password. By testing with just ssh VM1 it works fine, but inside fabric not, I search and seems to be a problem in paramiko, any idea?

Comment: give it a try again with `nc`, asuming it is available in the VMs

Comment: When updating to openssh-server 1:7.3p1 I could managed to jump to all VMs, including third jump. I did not use nc.